# Ubuntu doesn't work :UUID=xxxx does not exist

Tags: boot, mount, uuid

My computer has two operating systems, Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Today, when I tried to get into Ubuntu (I already laid it aside for about one week), the whole screen showed pure purple for at least 10 minutes, so I forced the computer to shutdown. Then when I tried to get into Ubuntu again, it showed:

[image]

Then I tried to open Ubuntu in recovery mode,but the outcome was same. And I also tried this solution:[missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) - Linux Mint Forums](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=47594) which doesn't work either.
At last I run `fsck.ext4 -y /dev/sda1`(where the root is),and showed:

[image]

Anyone know how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Did you recently install a Windows Update?

Comment: @user535733 Good observation. The FS is vfat.

Comment: @user535733 I think so.

Comment: Your output indicates the the filesystem is VFAT intead of EXT, which means you have some strange non-standard install of Ubuntu. We need to know about that.

Comment: I partition my disk manually when installing Ubuntu: '/' primary partition Ext4 30720MB, '/boot' primary partition Ext4 1024MB，'/home' logical partition Ext4 51200MB，'/tmp' logical partition Ext4 10240MB，'/usr' logical partition Ext4 102400MB，'/var' logical partition Ext4 10240MB，swap logical partition  10240MB